# Querying nested arrays in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection in MongoDB, where my data looks  like below. I am using NodeJS 12.X  platform along with Mongoose at backend for my application . Since i am new to development background, kindly help me in it.

**Collection Data in DB :**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("603faf38150786680421b51f"),
        "conversationMetricName" : [
                {
                        "metric" : "nConnected",
                        "stats" : {
                                "count" : 3
                        }
                },
                {
                        "metric" : "tAbandon",
                        "stats" : {
                                "max" : 2779,
                                "min" : 2779,
                                "count" : 1,
                                "sum" : 2779
                        }
                },
                {
                        "metric" : "tAcd",
                        "stats" : {
                                "max" : 2779,
                                "min" : 2779,
                                "count" : 1,
                                "sum" : 2779
                        }
                }
        ],
        "conversationInterval" : "2021-01-18T18:30:00.000Z/2021-01-19T18:30:00.000Z",
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("603faf38150786680421b520"),
        "conversationMetricName" : [
                {
                        "metric" : "nConnected",
                        "stats" : {
                                "count" : 19
                        }
                },
                {
                        "metric" : "tAbandon",
                        "stats" : {
                                "max" : 293745,
                                "min" : 214878,
                                "count" : 2,
                                "sum" : 508623
                        }
                },
                
        ],
        "conversationInterval" : "2021-01-19T18:30:00.000Z/2021-01-20T18:30:00.000Z",
        "__v" : 0
}
}
```

**Expected Response :**

```
{
chart:{

   date: [2021-01-18T18:30:00.000Z/2021-01-19T18:30:00.000Z, 2021-01-19T18:30:00.000Z/2021-01-20T18:30:00.000Z],
   nConnected: [3,19],
   tAbandon: [1,2],
   tAcd: [1,0],
   
   },

}
```

Could anyone advise me , how to filter the data as like above using their Counts value.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the sort method

collection.sort( { count: 1 } )

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor.sort

Comment: Hi @n7f , Actually i am trying to retrieve the desired response as posted above . Here i am not doing the sorting functionality. I can able to get the dates value, but remaining responses i am not sure how to retrieve count value  inside the array in respect with dates.